# Using jQuery to recall a function window onblur+ onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery

hI got a problem to use jQuery to recall afunction **if** window is on focus.
And when window is not on focus (onblur) so pause that function until window is on focus again.

Here is my code:

```
function functiondosomething (user_id) {

var myInterval;
var time_delay = 1000;


    $(window).focus(function () {

 setTimeout(function() { functiondosomething (user_id); }, time_delay);


    }).blur(function () {
        clearTimeout(myInterval); // Clearing interval on window blur

    });

 setTimeout(function() { functiondosomething (user_id); }, time_delay);// ## problem here

}
```

**My problem is :**

1. When I remove that line (which I marked problem here above.) the
   function will not work at first time until I click out of window to
   make it onblur and come back on focus again, so it starting to work.
2. If I let that line (which I marked problem here above.) be there,
   the function could not pause, even I click out of window to make it
   be onblur.
3. When I click onfocus it start working and stop. I have to click out
   of window and focus the window again again and again. Something like it need to be activate by clicking out of window and clicking back to window again.

   What should I do ?

Comment: myInterval = setTimeout

Comment: Hi, I have tried it, but it could not tell the fucntion to stop working even I click out of document (make it onblur)

Comment: Where are you calling this `functiondosomething` and why are you attaching `onfocus` etc. inside it?

Comment: From mainpage I use : $(document).ready(function() to call function init_page() in this document. And from init_page() I call functiondosomething() here.

Comment: But why are you attaching these events inside this function (when all they do is to call that function again)

Comment: I have many reasons, the most important is the variable that I will use (user_id). Out side this function there many complex function concern to this. So that´s why I have to do it inside here.

Comment: But it does nothing except attaching these event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems here:

1. You're not setting `myInterval` so when you call `clearTimeout(myInterval)` it's not clearing anything.
2. You're using the same function to set up your listeners and call `setTimeout` recursively. This means your handlers are being set every time you recur, and the recursion means it will run whether the handlers run or not.

I think you need to separate things a bit:

```js
function functiondosomething(user_id) {
  // Do stuff...
}

function setupHandlers(user_id) {
  var myInterval;
  var time_delay = 1000;

  function doSomethingWrapper() { 
    functiondosomething(user_id);
    myInterval = setTimeout(doSomethingWrapper, time_delay); 
  }

  $(window).focus(function () {
    doSomethingWrapper();
  }).blur(function () {
    clearTimeout(myInterval); // Clearing interval on window blur
  });
  doSomethingWrapper();
};
```

Comment: Hi my problem is, I need to let the dosomethingfunction stand alone out of anything. WHy, Because beside it, there´re many functions concern to this. It can make problem for other function.

Comment: No this should be outside. See `functiondosomething` is defined inside `setupHandlers`.

Comment: Now I can see it cause the problem to call this function. Could you please point me, How can I call this function from initepage () ?

Because now the function functiondosomething is inside the function() and it can not be called from init_page.

Comment: Oh, if you need the functiondosomething elsewhere just pull it out of this function. Here, I'll make an edit.

Comment: Hi yes thank you.. Because afte I test this I found Ihave to click it out and in again and again to activate the dosomething function.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe the focus event is triggered properly the way I have it set up I'll make another edit to call the function manually.

Comment: @PoramatFin I made a few changes, because I think you wanted `functiondosomething` to be called repeatedly, which mine wasn't doing. Let me know if this works.

Comment: It´s working now But so stupid with Windows, doesn´t wok :S

Even I click out of the document (onblur) the window still not pause this function. But work with other browse

Comment: Hmmm... it seams IE handles blur and focus differently: http://api.jquery.com/focusout/
Try `focusin` and `focusout` instead of `focus` and `blur` maybe?

Comment: I fear it will work with window but do not work with other browse. I have no idea :S